# how to split a line using a comma except for one field in a line

Tags: split, powershell-2.0

I'm capturing a string into a variable in my script and I'm trying to split the string using a comma as a delimiter. I want to leave the third field as is without splitting it, so that I can use it as it is. Could anyone please guide me how it can be done in PowerShell?

```
$var=1,ABCD4,345,348.89,347846,457835
```

When I use `$var.split(',')`, I get this:

```
1
ABCD4
345
348.89
347846
457835
```

But what I need is this:

```
1
ABCD4
345,348.89
347846
457835
```

Comment: trying to see if i can read the third field and fourth field into a varaiable while i'am splitting, Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

About using some Regex like this:

```
($var -Replace '([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)', "$1|$2|$3,$4|$5|$6").Split("|")
```